# PreSave/PrePersist/BeforeSave Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data

I'm having a bad time trying to find documentation about how to listen to this events using neo4j and spring data. I found some examples/similar question here in stack overflow but they all refer to SDN4 or before.

By any chance, any of you, have found some examples/documentation about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about Spring Data Neo4j 6, right?

There is now the functionality of a `BeforeBindCallback<T>` in place.
Whenever there is a save or update, SDN will call all registered callback beans before persisting the entity.

In your configuration you would define something like

```
@Bean
public BeforeBindCallback<MyEntity> beforeBindMyEntityCallback() {
    return entity -> {
        entity.setName("AnotherName");
        return entity;
    };
}
```

and you can, like every other manually created bean, also provide other dependencies in the parameter list of the bean creation, if needed.

I created a very small example here https://github.com/meistermeier/neo4j-issues-examples/tree/master/so-67424479

This is really missing from the documentation, you are right.

Comment: Gerrit, thank you much. I forgot to update this question. A few days ago I reached out Michael Simons and he provided the same information. You two are the bests :D.

Comment: Hi Gerrit, how can I know if it is a create, update, or delete operation? Thank you